# C++ int undefined behaviour when stored as RTC_NOINIT_ATTR (ESP32)

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm programming an ESP32 using VSCode. I have the following simple script:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

RTC_DATA_ATTR int counter1 = 0;
RTC_NOINIT_ATTR int counter2 = 0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.printf("RTC programme running, counter1 = %d; counter2 = %d\n",counter1,counter2);
delay(3000);
counter1++;
counter2++;
esp_restart();
}

void loop() {
  // nothing needed here
}
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 0
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 1
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 2
...
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 109811943
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 109811944
RTC programme running, counter1 = 0; counter2 = 109811945
...
```

(where the value of *counter2* is a random value). I've tried various combinations of *int*, *uint32_t* etc. but still get the random value. It's caused by the *RTC_NOINIT_ATTR* definition but it's what I need for the eventual application. Anything I can be doing differently?

Comment: I'd guess that the initialiser for `counter2` is ignored and if you've never written to `counter2` then it contains junk data

Comment: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7045

Comment: Adding the esp_reset_reason code at the beginning of setup() does work, thank you.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, you could write an answer

Comment: @Juraj I know nothing about this topic the link was just the result of a google of `RTC_NOINIT_ATTR`

Answer (score 3):

The RTC memory of the ESP32 is retained over software reset and deep sleep.

The RTC_DATA_ATTR and [RTC_NOINIT_ATTR](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/memory-types.html#rtc-slow-memory) macros have linker directives to move the variables to addresses mapped into the RTC memory.

**Variable with RTC_NOINIT_ATTR is not initialized at program start to not erase the value stored in the RTC memory.** (RTC_DATA_ATTR variables value is available only in deep sleep stubs, which are small functions running in RTC memory right after wakeup before the normal program starts.)

To initialize the RTC_NOINIT_ATTR variable only on power-up, you can [check the reset reason](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/system.html#reset-reason) in setup() and initialize the variable only on some [reset reasons](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/system.html#_CPPv418esp_reset_reason_t).

Answer (score 0):

I added this at the start of the setup() function:

```
  esp_reset_reason_t reason = esp_reset_reason();
  if ((reason != ESP_RST_DEEPSLEEP) && (reason != ESP_RST_SW))
  {
    counter2 = 0;
  }
```

It now works more or less as it should...